# Plot the solution of a system of linear inequalities

Tags: python, matplotlib, convex-polygon

I have two arrays of numbers from [-1,1]:

`a = 2*np.random.sample(100)-1` and 
`b = 2*np.random.sample(100)-1`. These two arrays define the following system of linear inequalities

a[i]*x + b[i]*y <= 1 for i = 0,1,..., 99

The solution-set of this system is a convex polygon. How to draw it using matplotlib? As I understand,`fill_between` allows to do this only for case of two inequalities.

Comment: Please provide the full listing of the code you tried and an example of desired result if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fillplots package (http://fillplots.readthedocs.org) that does exactly what you are looking for. A few examples are available at http://fillplots.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted. I wonder to know why matplotlib doesn't have such useful function.